# Performance difference RBFS - A*

Tags: search, a-star

I've implemented the RBFS as defined in AIMA and wanted to compare it to an implementation of A*. When I try it out on an instance from the TSPlib (ulyssis16 - 16 cities), both come up with a correct solution, the memory usage is also correct (exponential for A*, linear for RBFS). The only weird thing is that the RBFS algorithm is much faster than A* when it shouldn't be the case. A* finished in about 3.5 minutes, RBFS takes only a few seconds. When I count the number of visits for each node, A* visits a lot more nodes than RBFS. That also seems counter-intuitive.

Is this because of the trivial instance? I can't really try it out on a bigger instance as my computer doesn't have enough memory for that.

Has anyone got any suggestions? Both algorithms seem to be correct according to their specifications, their results and memory usage. Only the execution time seems off...

I already looked everywhere but couldn't find anything about a difference in their search strategy. Except for the fact that RBFS can revisit nodes.

Thanks

Jasper

Edit 1: AIMA corresponds to the book Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach by Russel and Norvig.
Edit 2: TSPlib is a set of instances of the TSP problem (http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/)
Edit 4: The code for the A* algorithm is given as follows. This should be correct.
    def graph_search(problem, fringe):
        """Search through the successors of a problem to find a goal.
        The argument fringe should be an empty queue.
        If two paths reach a state, only use the best one. [Fig. 3.18]"""
        closed = {}
        fringe.append(Node(problem.initial))
        while fringe:
            node = fringe.pop()
            if problem.goal_test(node.state):
                return node
            if node.state not in closed:
                closed[node.state] = True
                fringe.extend(node.expand(problem))
        return None

```
def best_first_graph_search(problem, f):
    return graph_search(problem, PriorityQueue(f,min))

def astar_graph_search(problem, h):
    def f(n):
        return n.path_cost + h(n)
    return best_first_graph_search(problem, f)
```

Where problem is a variable containing details about the problem to be solved (when the goal is reached, how to generate successors, the initial state,...). A node contains the path on how to reach that state by storing the parent node and some other utility functions. Here is an older version of this code http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/search.py) For the TSP problem, the tours are created incrementally. The used heuristic is the minimal spanning tree on the nodes that are not yet visited.

The code for RBFS is as follows:
    def rbfs(problem, h):
        def f(n):
            return n.path_cost + h(n)

```
    def rbfs_helper(node, bound):
        #print("Current bound: ", bound)

        problem.visit(node)

        if (problem.goal_test(node.state)):
            return [node, f(node)]

        backup = {}
        backup[node.state.id] = f(node)

        succ = list(node.expand(problem))

        if (not succ):
            return [None, float("inf")]

        for v in succ:
            backup[v.state.id] = max(f(v), backup[node.state.id])

        while(True):
            sortedSucc = sorted(succ, key=lambda node: backup[node.state.id])

            best = sortedSucc[0]

            if (backup[best.state.id] > bound):
                return [None, backup[best.state.id]]

            if (len(sortedSucc) == 1):
                [resultNode, backup[best.state.id]] = rbfs_helper(best, bound)
            else:
                alternative = sortedSucc[1]
                [resultNode, backup[best.state.id]] = rbfs_helper(best, min(bound, backup[alternative.state.id]))

            if (resultNode != None):
                return [resultNode, backup[best.state.id]]

    [node, v] = rbfs_helper(Node(problem.initial), float("inf"))

    return node
```

It also uses the problem and node as defined above. Those were specifically designed to be used as generic elements.

Comment: There are a huge number of factors that might influence this.  What data structure did you use for the priority queue in A*?  What puzzle are you trying to solve?  I think that you might need to post some code here for us to look over in order to get a good answer.

Comment: I don't think A\* should visit more nodes than BFS  under any circumstances, assuming the heuristic is admissible.

Comment: I added some additional information on those items and the code of both search algorithms. The A* code was given to me. I'm not a fantastic python3 programmer so it might be possible to optimize some things I missed.